# Network based /home partition

Tags: networking

I have a large workstation with a large SSD and a 320GB HDD, and a laptop with no compatible hard drive on hand. My workstation can only drive one monitor while my laptop can drive two (just the way it works out with the cables I have). I currently have my laptop booting from a USB drive and I have Synergy installed, but I want a fair amount of storage on each machine. I have both connected via ethernet currently. Is it possible to set things up such that my desktop shares a large partition on the HDD with the laptop over ethernet that my laptop can use as its /home partition while still being able to access it on the desktop? Or is this a fantastically terrible idea from the start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be a little cautious 'exporting' a home directory from the desktop to the laptop, but you could.  You should be fine to export another partition/folder from the desktop using **nfs**, which you'd then 'mount' from the laptop.

Alternatively you could mount a directory over SSH (simple and useful for lightweight file use and browsing).  If you are using the nautilus file manager try Menu->File->Connect to Server (select SSH).

Alternatively you might want to use X11 forwarding.  Which would let you use remote apps from the desktop on the laptop.  Say run gedit on the desktop, but have the window and input on your laptop.  This would also allow you to bypass exports and mounts this way.